# The try/catch block fails to catch socket connection exception

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to connect to a socket that DOES NOT exist for testing purposes. In such case, an exception is thrown and I expect it to be caught in the following try/catch block. `createConnection` is imported from the `net` package.

```
try {
    createConnection(8000, "127.0.0.1")
}
catch(exception) {
    console.log("FAILED")
}
```

However, the try/catch fails and it leads to a crash by producing the following error:

```
node:events:368
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 8000
}
```

What's going wrong here? and if that is supposed to be like that, then how can I safeguard the application from crashing when a socket is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try-catch` block does only catch errors the are emitted through a `throw` in `createConnection`.

The error in question however is an error that is reported through an `error` event that you need to listen to.

`createConnection` returns a `Socket` that implements `EventEmitter` on which you can register listeners for e.g. error events.

So it has to be:

```
createConnection(…)
.on('error', err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: I did, `on.("error")` didn't work either!

Comment: Oh, yeah, It should be directly bound the reference and not through the third argument which is a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this function is asynchronous and you have to listen for `error` event

```
const connection = createConnection(8000, "127.0.0.1")
connection.on('error', error => {
  // handle error
})
```

If you really want to use `try...catch`:

```
function createConn(port, ip) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connection = createConnection(port, ip)
    connection.on('ready', resolve)
    connection.on('error', reject)
  })
}

try {
  await createConn(8000, "127.0.0.1")
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: That's why JavaScript is said to be weird :D

Comment: Are you sure that this works? Isn’t the `error` event emitted after `resolve(connection)` is called? Shouldn’t the `resolve` be in the listening/ready callback?

Comment: @t.niese you are right, it doesn't make sense

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder `That's why JavaScript is said to be weird :D` not really. That's just the difference between having an even driven API and a synchronous one. It is true that JavaScript (because it is not multithreaded) is heavily event driven, but event driven APIs also exists in many other languages. There are other really language related things that are wired about JavaScript, but the same is true for other languages as well.

Comment: @t.niese: That's true but even events in other languages work differently. Although the event pattern is actually the observable pattern, other languages such as C# do not force you to listen to an event for handling errors.